# Perform authentication to Polarion webservice with Savon

Tags: savon

I am attempting to follow the discussion [here](http://forums.polarion.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=19274) using Ruby and Savon.  I am able to retrieve a session ID, but whenever I perform a request from the clients that require authentication (tracker), I receive an Authorization Failed error.

```
require 'Savon'

tracker_url = 'http://myserver/polarion/ws/services/TrackerWebService?wsdl'
session_url = 'http://myserver/polarion/ws/services/SessionWebService?wsdl'

# todo handle bad login credentials gracefully
session_client = Savon.client(wsdl: session_url)
response = session_client.call(:log_in, message: {user_name: 'lsimons', password: 'mypassword'})
session_id = response.header[:session_id]

puts "Session ID: #{session_id}"

tracker_client = Savon.client(wsdl: tracker_url, soap_header: {"session" => session_id},     headers: {"sessionID" => session_id})

puts "Requesting Workitem"
begin
    tracker_client.call(:get_work_item_by_id, message: {project_id: 'myProject', workitem_id: 'myWorkitem'})
rescue
    puts "Client call failed"
end
```

This code creates the following SOAP request for the tracker_client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins0="http://ws.polarion.com/TrackerWebService-impl" xmlns:ins1="http://ws.polarion.com/types" xmlns:ins2="http://ws.polarion.com/TrackerWebService-types" xmlns:ins3="http://ws.polarion.com/ProjectWebService-types" xmlns:tns1="http://ws.polarion.com/TrackerWebService" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header>
        <session>2164640482421325916</session>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <tns1:getWorkItemById>
            <ins0:projectId>myProject</ins0:projectId>
            <ins0:workitemId>myWorkitem</ins0:workitemId>
        </tns1:getWorkItemById>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

However, in the forum discussion, the sessionID element occurs before the header.  I didn't think this was possible with standard SOAP?  Is there a way to achieve this with Savon or am I misinterpreting the forum discussion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem following the same thread. This is how I made it work (by replicating the response headers of the log_in request):

```
tracker_client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: tracker_url,
  soap_header: {
    "ns1:sessionID" => session_id,
    :attributes! => {
      "ns1:sessionID" => {
        "env:actor"           => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next",
        "env:mustUnderstand"  => "0",
        "xmlns:ns1"           => "http://ws.polarion.com/session"
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: It seems like the critical attribute is xmlns:ns1.  I can comment out env:actor and env:mustUnderstand and still receive a response.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Old question but thought I can add some info to hopefully help somebody.

I am using `lolsoap` to talk to polarion. In the above resulting document, the `sessionID` element is wiped off any namespaces and attributes. Also the assessment is right that `actor` and `mustUnderstand` attributes seem irrelevant.

To add header properly though with all fluff, one needs to get the `Nokogiri::XML::Node` and `dup` it, then add it to the header of the doc. This is a bug in `nokogiri`/`libxml2` that adding child elements can often break namespaces unless Node is cloned before adding [1].

In `lolsoap` it is done something like:

```
auth_header = login_response.nokogiri_doc.xpath("//*[local-name()='sessionID']")[0].dup
other_request.header.__node__ << auth_header
```

Please note the `dup` operation. `header.__node__` is just the header `Nokogiri::XML::Element` of a random SOAP request.

The `dup` operation makes adding desired element into another one with all necessary namespaces and attributes properly defined.

I don't know if `savon` allows one to directly touch request XML but I guess it does. Thus HTH

[1] https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1200